# future not working with javax.mail

Tags: multithreading, clojure, jakarta-mail, future

I'm playing with `future` and and can't seem to get it to work with `javax.mail`. For example, for fun, I'm trying to set up a compojure handler to grab a bunch of emails and put them into a database, but deliver a response to the client before the emails have all been gathered and inserted.

I have a few `println`s going on in the `import-posts` function (below), and when I run this from the repl, it works fine, printing `142 journal messages.` the first time (because the db is empty), and `No new messages.` the second time. When I try it by running the local development jetty server, I get a `println` output of `142 journal messages` every time I load the page, and they never get inserted into the db. Okay, so then I tried to import them into the db from the repl and *then* try it from jetty, and I still got `142 journal messages` every time. What's the best way to accomplish this?

#### compojure handler:

```
(GET "/" request
     (if-let [usr_id (:id (friend/current-authentication))]
       (friend/authorize
         #{:pojagi.models.usr/user}

         ;; this is where I'm having trouble
         (do (future (let [folder (mail/get-folder mail/gmail "Inbox")]
                       (println "importing emails from " (.getName folder) ".")
                       (mail/import-posts usr_id folder)))
           (index/home)))


       (index/index (:flash request))))
```

#### function for importing emails:

```
(defn import-posts
  [usr_id ^javax.mail.Folder folder & {:keys [subject-term public?]}]
  (let [messages (get-latest-messages usr_id folder)
        journals (into [] (.search folder (SubjectTerm. (or subject-term "journal")) messages))]
    (println (count journals) "journal messages.")
    (if (< (count journals) 2)
      (println "No new messages.")
      (map
        (fn [journal]
          (println "inserting journal" (.getSubject journal))
          (let [[title created bodyparts uid :as post] [(.getSubject journal)
                                                        (-> journal .getSentDate .getTime (java.sql.Timestamp.))
                                                        (-> journal .getContent)
                                                        (-> folder (.getUID journal))]
                body (-> (.getBodyPart bodyparts 0)
                       .getDataHandler .getInputStream slurp md/md-to-html-string)]
            (post/insert {:title title :body body :created created :usr_id 4 :public true :email_uid uid})
            ))
        journals) )))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may have been bitten by the lazy-bug:

if you wrap a `doall` around the `map` it may help

```
(doall (map
    (fn [journal]
```

or `dorun` if you don't want to check the result after (dorun is like doall that does not hold the entire sequence, so less likely to run out of memory)

```
(dorun (map
    (fn [journal]
```

When you run import-posts from the repl, the repl prints the result of mapping the `fn [journal]` over the journals, which causes the side effect of inserting them into the database. **When jetty runs this nothing looks at the result**, the sequence remains lazily-unrealized, and the side effects to not take place.

Comment: hehe, it's my little pet name for this general class of bugs, where things only work in the REPL *because* the REPL is printing the result, then in production nothing happens. I just think it has a nice ring to it :-)

Comment: actually, this answer is problematic because it stops importing after like 27 emails (because it ran out of memory). How can you do it where you get around both the laziness and the running out of memory issue?

Answer (score 1):

After also attempting `for` because I was running out of memory, I finally figured out that `doseq` is a workable choice for this kind of side-effect producing activity, because it won't try to hold the entire collection in memory:

```
(defn import-posts
  [usr_id ^javax.mail.Folder folder & {:keys [subject-term public?]}]
  (let [last-uid (post/last-uid usr_id)
        messages (get-latest-messages usr_id folder last-uid)
        journals (into [] (.search folder (SubjectTerm. (or subject-term "journal")) messages))]
    (if (and (< (count journals) 2)
             (= last-uid (-> folder (.getUID (first journals)))))
      (println "No new messages.")
      (doseq [import (map
                       (fn [journal]
                         (println "inserting journal" (.getSubject journal))
                         (let [[title created bodyparts uid :as post] [(.getSubject journal)
                                                                       (-> journal .getSentDate .getTime (java.sql.Timestamp.))
                                                                       (-> journal .getContent)
                                                                       (-> folder (.getUID journal))]
                               body (-> (.getBodyPart bodyparts 0)
                                      .getDataHandler .getInputStream slurp md/md-to-html-string)]
                           (post/insert {:title title :body body :created created :usr_id 4 :public true :email_uid uid})))
                       journals)]
        import))))
```

Comment: dorun is like doall that does not hold the entire sequence

Comment: I added this comment to your answer and accepted. Thanks again!