# Future in closure not firing (Clojure)

Tags: clojure

I have a closure in which a `future` takes a `do` block. Each function inside the do block is provided by the arguments of the closure:

```
(defn accept-order
  [persist record track notify log] 
  (fn [sponsor order]
    (let [datetime (to-timestamp (local-now))
          order (merge order {:network_reviewed_at datetime
                              :workflow_state "unconfirmed"
                              :sponsor_id (:id sponsor)})]
      (future
        (do
          (persist order
                   (select-keys order [:network_reviewed_at
                                       :workflow_state
                                       :sponsor_id]))
          (record sponsor order true)
          (track)
          (notify sponsor order)
          (log sponsor order)))
      order)))
```

No function in the `do` block is fired. If I deref the future, it works. If I remove the future it works. If I run from a REPL, it works. But if I run `lein test`, it won't work.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Please add some details about how your tests are setup.  The `lein test` docs indicate: `$ lein test [TESTS] # run the tests in the TESTS namespaces, or all tests`.  Perhaps leiningen isn't detecting any tests and your accept-order function isn't being invoked and your future is never being invoked?  That is my initial "shot in the dark" guess.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly. It's definitely being invoked. In fact, the test passes otherwise. But the side effects (emails, Google analytics event, logging) do not fire. Oddly, the code executes when invoked from Compojure.

Comment: There's a similar SO question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436762/future-not-working-with-javax-mail, but I'm not using any sequences (I don't think).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a `(Thread/sleep 2000)` to a test invoking your function causes the future to run, so I'd venture a guess that Leiningen is killing the VM before your future gets to run (or at least before it manages to cause its side effects). Leiningen does kill the VM immediately after running tests.

As a side note, you don't need the `do`. `future` takes a body, not a single expression.

Comment: That's amazing. You nailed it.